# CakePHP - Adding a JS file to the 'script' block from a controller's beforeRender callback

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible to add a js file to view from a controller beforeRender()? Is it advisable? If not, and if I cannot use a View, should I just use the Event System?

Basically the idea is to have a plugin that I created inject a JS file into 'script' block of the Theme plugin (Separate plugin)

Answer (score 0):

After some more attempts I decided to go thru and use the Event System. I accomplished it this way:

```
<?php

namespace App\Event;

use Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface;    

class ApplicationListener implements EventListenerInterface {

    public function implementedEvents() {
        return [
            'View.beforeLayout' => 'injectJsFile'
        ];
    }

    public function injectJsFile(Event $event, $layoutFile){
      $event->getSubject()->Html->script('myscript', ['block' => 'script']);
    }

}
```

This does the job for me, but if there is a controller way or a better Event System way, I would love to hear it.

Comment: Why would you want to do this from a controller, this doesn't seem to be something that should necessarily be a controllers concern? Depending on what the theme plugin does, you could maybe set a view variable instead, and evaluate it in your view template, that way you have more control over this at the theme level. ps. the `getSubject()` method doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: @ndm, couldn't he just create an Helper and use `Helper::beforeRender` callback?

Comment: @arilia As far as the event system goes there's not much of a difference, as `Helper.beforeRender` just proxies `View.beforeRender`, but of course a custom helper and/or a custom event that explicitly allows controlling scripts to be embedded would work too, could very well be the better choice as it would be more encapsulated, but without knowing what exactly the theme plugin is doing, it's hard to give an overly concrete advice.

Comment: Thank you all! Since I wanted this to work with any theme, I did not have a concern of how the theme was setup, except for the fact that I assume a theme has the 'script' and 'css' blocks added.

Comment: I did not think a helper would work since, I believe, the theme needed to explicitily call out that helper in order for this to work. I simply wanted this process to inject scripts/css into any third party themes I had no control over.

Comment: @ndm, thanks for the getSubject() correct. I have fixed it.

Comment: If you don't have control over the theme, then using the helper is probably the most simple approach, though you don't really know whether the theme actually makes us of the default script block named `script`, or "where" it makes use of it. There's surely additional ways of handling this, DebugKit for example [**modifies the response body**](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/blob/3.16.1/src/ToolbarService.php#L285) and injects its script tag before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thanks @ndm. I have used an approach in the past similar to DebugKit as well that uses a DispatchFilter and taps into the afterDispatch event. That is a good process as it takes the question of whether the 'script' or 'css' blocks are set in the theme, out of the equation. For this time though I wanted to directly push the scripts/styles into the these blocks. The Listener approach I have taken is working and I will use it for now. Thank you!